# Plotting comorbidity data in a stacked circular bar chart

Tags: r, stacked-bar-chart, radial

I'm essentially wanting to create this terrible hand drawn graph (see below) for a dataset I have of where I want to illustrate the spread of comorbid diagnoses people with specific pain conditions have.

Larger image of below drawing here:

[image]

So, I have four diagnostic groups (FM, CR, CM, HC) and I have 94 reported conditions that are split into 11 categories (Neurological, Psychiatric, Pelvic, Cardiovascular, Autoimmune, Skin, Bone-Muscle-Joint, Digestive, Hormonal, Genetic, Vascular). I then have a column for frequency.

I specifically want to have the 11 categories separated into clusters, and then the first inner ring be the FM group, followed by CR, CM, and HC.

Absolutely any help is appreciated

I have failed at coding with ggplot , but I imagine this is still correct - just a sign of my ignorance.

Edit: Have added sample data and a link to larger image of example.

```
Category    Condition   Group   Frequency
Neurological    Epilepsy    FM  0
Neurological    Epilepsy    CR  1
Neurological    Epilepsy    CM  0
Neurological    Epilepsy    HC  1
Neurological    Chronic migraine    FM  2
Neurological    Chronic migraine    CR  3
Neurological    Chronic migraine    CM  7
Neurological    Chronic migraine    HC  0
Neurological    Autism  FM  1
Neurological    Autism  CR  1
Neurological    Autism  CM  1
Neurological    Autism  HC  0
Neurological    Postherpetic neuralgia  FM  0
Neurological    Postherpetic neuralgia  CR  0
Neurological    Postherpetic neuralgia  CM  1
Neurological    Postherpetic neuralgia  HC  0
Neurological    Chiari Malformation FM  0
Neurological    Chiari Malformation CR  0
Neurological    Chiari Malformation CM  1
Neurological    Chiari Malformation HC  0
Neurological    Syringomyelia   FM  0
Neurological    Syringomyelia   CR  0
Neurological    Syringomyelia   CM  1
Neurological    Syringomyelia   HC  0
Neurological    Secondary Fibromyalgia  FM  0
Neurological    Secondary Fibromyalgia  CR  7
Neurological    Secondary Fibromyalgia  CM  0
Neurological    Secondary Fibromyalgia  HC  0
Neurological    Trigeminal neuralgia    FM  0
Neurological    Trigeminal neuralgia    CR  1
Neurological    Trigeminal neuralgia    CM  0
Neurological    Trigeminal neuralgia    HC  0
Neurological    Diabetes    FM  3
Neurological    Diabetes    CR  3
Neurological    Diabetes    CM  2
Neurological    Diabetes    HC  0
Neurological    Neurofibromatosis 1 FM  0
Neurological    Neurofibromatosis 1 CR  0
Neurological    Neurofibromatosis 1 CM  1
Neurological    Neurofibromatosis 1 HC  0
Neurological    Narcolepsy  FM  2
Neurological    Narcolepsy  CR  0
Neurological    Narcolepsy  CM  1
Neurological    Narcolepsy  HC  0
Neurological    Neuropathy  FM  0
Neurological    Neuropathy  CR  0
Neurological    Neuropathy  CM  1
Neurological    Neuropathy  HC  0
Neurological    CNS demyelinating disease   FM  0
Neurological    CNS demyelinating disease   CR  0
Neurological    CNS demyelinating disease   CM  1
Neurological    CNS demyelinating disease   HC  0
Neurological    Chronic fatigue syndrome    FM  12
Neurological    Chronic fatigue syndrome    CR  1
Neurological    Chronic fatigue syndrome    CM  0
Neurological    Chronic fatigue syndrome    HC  0
Neurological    Occipital neuralgia FM  0
Neurological    Occipital neuralgia CR  1
Neurological    Occipital neuralgia CM  0
Neurological    Occipital neuralgia HC  0
Neurological    Ulnar neuritis  FM  0
Neurological    Ulnar neuritis  CR  1
Neurological    Ulnar neuritis  CM  0
Neurological    Ulnar neuritis  HC  0
Psychiatric Anxiety FM  33
Psychiatric Anxiety CR  18
Psychiatric Anxiety CM  22
Psychiatric Anxiety HC  1
Psychiatric Depression  FM  38
Psychiatric Depression  CR  23
Psychiatric Depression  CM  16
Psychiatric Depression  HC  2
Psychiatric PTSD    FM  11
```

Comment: Provide example data please. Also the awesome hand drawn image is too small, add a bigger resolution. Try searching for "circular stacked bar chart", for example, this post might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70813947/680068

Comment: Thanks @zx8754 I've added a higher res image and a snippet of code. The link is a great start for me, but I'm still quite lost in it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's quite a tall order to achieve this type of plot within ggplot, but it can be done with a bit of effort using data manipulation and some manual tweaks:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geomtextpath)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), fct_inorder)) %>%
  mutate(position = as.numeric(Condition) + as.numeric(Category)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(position, Frequency)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(5, 10, 15, 20), color = 'navy', linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = position, y = -3, yend = 0), 
               data = data.frame(position = c(1, 9, 20, 29, 39, 47, 55, 
                                              62, 72, 80, 89))) +
  geom_textpath(aes(y = -1.5, label = Category, group = Category), 
                textcolour = 'black', fontface = "bold",
                size = 4, text_only = TRUE) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Group), position = position_stack(), width = 0.4) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#f5925f", "#6663bc", "#8d8b8e", "#98d75c")) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = 'none') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-3, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-20, 20)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 96), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_void(base_size = 18) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f0f0ff"))
```

[image]

---

**Data used - fabricated for example**

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", 
"Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", 
"Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", 
"Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", 
"Neuro", "Neuro", "Neuro", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", 
"Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", 
"Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", 
"Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", 
"Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", 
"Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", "Psych", 
"Psych", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", 
"Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", 
"Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", 
"Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", 
"Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Pelvic", "Cardio", "Cardio", 
"Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", 
"Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", 
"Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", 
"Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", 
"Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Cardio", "Autoimmune", 
"Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", 
"Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", 
"Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", 
"Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", 
"Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", 
"Autoimmune", "Autoimmune", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", 
"Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", 
"Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", 
"Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "Skin", "MSK", 
"MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", 
"MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", 
"MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "MSK", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", 
"Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Digestive", "Hormonal", 
"Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", 
"Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", 
"Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", 
"Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", 
"Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Hormonal", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", 
"Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", 
"Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", 
"Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", 
"Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", 
"Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Genetic", "Vascular", 
"Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", 
"Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", 
"Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", 
"Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular", "Vascular"), 
    Condition = c("Epilepsy", "Epilepsy", "Epilepsy", "Epilepsy", 
    "Chronic migraine", "Chronic migraine", "Chronic migraine", 
    "Chronic migraine", "Parkinson's disease", "Parkinson's disease", 
    "Parkinson's disease", "Parkinson's disease", "Alzheimer's disease", 
    "Alzheimer's disease", "Alzheimer's disease", "Alzheimer's disease", 
    "Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS)", "Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS)", 
    "Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS)", "Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS)", 
    "Spinal muscular atrophy", "Spinal muscular atrophy", "Spinal muscular atrophy", 
    "Spinal muscular atrophy", "Narcolepsy", "Narcolepsy", "Narcolepsy", 
    "Narcolepsy", "Depression", "Depression", "Depression", "Depression", 
    "Bipolar disorder", "Bipolar disorder", "Bipolar disorder", 
    "Bipolar disorder", "Schizophrenia", "Schizophrenia", "Schizophrenia", 
    "Schizophrenia", "Post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD)", 
    "Post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD)", "Post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD)", 
    "Post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD)", "Anxiety disorder", 
    "Anxiety disorder", "Anxiety disorder", "Anxiety disorder", 
    "Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder (OCD)", "Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder (OCD)", 
    "Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder (OCD)", "Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder (OCD)", 
    "Dissociative identity disorder", "Dissociative identity disorder", 
    "Dissociative identity disorder", "Dissociative identity disorder", 
    "Autism spectrum disorder", "Autism spectrum disorder", "Autism spectrum disorder", 
    "Autism spectrum disorder", "Attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder (ADHD)", 
    "Attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder (ADHD)", "Attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder (ADHD)", 
    "Attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder (ADHD)", "Eating disorders", 
    "Eating disorders", "Eating disorders", "Eating disorders", 
    "Endometriosis", "Endometriosis", "Endometriosis", "Endometriosis", 
    "Pelvic inflammatory disease", "Pelvic inflammatory disease", 
    "Pelvic inflammatory disease", "Pelvic inflammatory disease", 
    "Uterine fibroids", "Uterine fibroids", "Uterine fibroids", 
    "Uterine fibroids", "Ovarian cysts", "Ovarian cysts", "Ovarian cysts", 
    "Ovarian cysts", "Prostatitis", "Prostatitis", "Prostatitis", 
    "Prostatitis", "Erectile dysfunction", "Erectile dysfunction", 
    "Erectile dysfunction", "Erectile dysfunction", "Pelvic organ prolapse", 
    "Pelvic organ prolapse", "Pelvic organ prolapse", "Pelvic organ prolapse", 
    "Benign prostatic hyperplasia (BPH)", "Benign prostatic hyperplasia (BPH)", 
    "Benign prostatic hyperplasia (BPH)", "Benign prostatic hyperplasia (BPH)", 
    "Hypertension", "Hypertension", "Hypertension", "Hypertension", 
    "Atherosclerosis", "Atherosclerosis", "Atherosclerosis", 
    "Atherosclerosis", "Coronary artery disease", "Coronary artery disease", 
    "Coronary artery disease", "Coronary artery disease", "Heart failure", 
    "Heart failure", "Heart failure", "Heart failure", "Atrial fibrillation", 
    "Atrial fibrillation", "Atrial fibrillation", "Atrial fibrillation", 
    "Myocardial infarction", "Myocardial infarction", "Myocardial infarction", 
    "Myocardial infarction", "Stroke", "Stroke", "Stroke", "Stroke", 
    "Congestive heart failure", "Congestive heart failure", "Congestive heart failure", 
    "Congestive heart failure", "Peripheral artery disease", 
    "Peripheral artery disease", "Peripheral artery disease", 
    "Peripheral artery disease", "Rheumatoid arthritis", "Rheumatoid arthritis", 
    "Rheumatoid arthritis", "Rheumatoid arthritis", "Lupus", 
    "Lupus", "Lupus", "Lupus", "Celiac disease", "Celiac disease", 
    "Celiac disease", "Celiac disease", "Type 1 diabetes", "Type 1 diabetes", 
    "Type 1 diabetes", "Type 1 diabetes", "Graves' disease", 
    "Graves' disease", "Graves' disease", "Graves' disease", 
    "Inflammatory bowel disease", "Inflammatory bowel disease", 
    "Inflammatory bowel disease", "Inflammatory bowel disease", 
    "Hashimoto's thyroiditis", "Hashimoto's thyroiditis", "Hashimoto's thyroiditis", 
    "Hashimoto's thyroiditis", "Acne", "Acne", "Acne", "Acne", 
    "Dermatitis", "Dermatitis", "Dermatitis", "Dermatitis", "Eczema", 
    "Eczema", "Eczema", "Eczema", "Vitiligo", "Vitiligo", "Vitiligo", 
    "Vitiligo", "Rosacea", "Rosacea", "Rosacea", "Rosacea", "Hives", 
    "Hives", "Hives", "Hives", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", 
    "Melanoma", "Arthritis", "Arthritis", "Arthritis", "Arthritis", 
    "Osteoporosis", "Osteoporosis", "Osteoporosis", "Osteoporosis", 
    "Gout", "Gout", "Gout", "Gout", "Tendinitis", "Tendinitis", 
    "Tendinitis", "Tendinitis", "Carpal tunnel syndrome", "Carpal tunnel syndrome", 
    "Carpal tunnel syndrome", "Carpal tunnel syndrome", "Sciatica", 
    "Sciatica", "Sciatica", "Sciatica", "Irritable bowel syndrome (IBS)", 
    "Irritable bowel syndrome (IBS)", "Irritable bowel syndrome (IBS)", 
    "Irritable bowel syndrome (IBS)", "Gastroesophageal reflux disease (GERD)", 
    "Gastroesophageal reflux disease (GERD)", "Gastroesophageal reflux disease (GERD)", 
    "Gastroesophageal reflux disease (GERD)", "Gastritis", "Gastritis", 
    "Gastritis", "Gastritis", "Ulcerative colitis", "Ulcerative colitis", 
    "Ulcerative colitis", "Ulcerative colitis", "Crohn's disease", 
    "Crohn's disease", "Crohn's disease", "Crohn's disease", 
    "Gallstones", "Gallstones", "Gallstones", "Gallstones", "Hepatitis C", 
    "Hepatitis C", "Hepatitis C", "Hepatitis C", "Diverticulitis", 
    "Diverticulitis", "Diverticulitis", "Diverticulitis", "Gastric ulcer", 
    "Gastric ulcer", "Gastric ulcer", "Gastric ulcer", "Type 2 diabetes", 
    "Type 2 diabetes", "Type 2 diabetes", "Type 2 diabetes", 
    "Hypothyroidism", "Hypothyroidism", "Hypothyroidism", "Hypothyroidism", 
    "Hyperthyroidism", "Hyperthyroidism", "Hyperthyroidism", 
    "Hyperthyroidism", "Addison's disease", "Addison's disease", 
    "Addison's disease", "Addison's disease", "Cushing's syndrome", 
    "Cushing's syndrome", "Cushing's syndrome", "Cushing's syndrome", 
    "Menopause", "Menopause", "Menopause", "Menopause", "Gigantism", 
    "Gigantism", "Gigantism", "Gigantism", "Down syndrome", "Down syndrome", 
    "Down syndrome", "Down syndrome", "Cystic fibrosis", "Cystic fibrosis", 
    "Cystic fibrosis", "Cystic fibrosis", "Sickle cell anemia", 
    "Sickle cell anemia", "Sickle cell anemia", "Sickle cell anemia", 
    "Huntington's disease", "Huntington's disease", "Huntington's disease", 
    "Huntington's disease", "Hemophilia", "Hemophilia", "Hemophilia", 
    "Hemophilia", "Duchenne muscular dystrophy", "Duchenne muscular dystrophy", 
    "Duchenne muscular dystrophy", "Duchenne muscular dystrophy", 
    "Turner syndrome", "Turner syndrome", "Turner syndrome", 
    "Turner syndrome", "Klinefelter syndrome", "Klinefelter syndrome", 
    "Klinefelter syndrome", "Klinefelter syndrome", "Deep vein thrombosis (DVT)", 
    "Deep vein thrombosis (DVT)", "Deep vein thrombosis (DVT)", 
    "Deep vein thrombosis (DVT)", "Varicose veins", "Varicose veins", 
    "Varicose veins", "Varicose veins", "Pulmonary embolism", 
    "Pulmonary embolism", "Pulmonary embolism", "Pulmonary embolism", 
    "Abdominal aortic aneurysm", "Abdominal aortic aneurysm", 
    "Abdominal aortic aneurysm", "Abdominal aortic aneurysm", 
    "Thoracic aortic aneurysm", "Thoracic aortic aneurysm", "Thoracic aortic aneurysm", 
    "Thoracic aortic aneurysm", "Aneurysm", "Aneurysm", "Aneurysm", 
    "Aneurysm"), Group = c("FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", 
    "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", 
    "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC", "FM", "CR", "CM", "HC"
    ), Frequency = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    0L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
    4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-336L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: there is also a package called sunburstR that creates html plots like this and they are interactive- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sunburstR/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Allan! I'm trying to replicate with your fabricated data+code. I get the following circles https://imgur.com/a/tRgZMUQ and these warning messages: 
1: In eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: Removed 336 rows containing missing values (`position_stack()`). 
4: Removed 336 rows containing missing values (`geom_textpath()`). 

Although, this was just to replicate your code to understand it before modifying to my code "data.csv". Do you have any ideas? Thanks again